# How to Share List ListBox items using ShareStatusTask in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, listitem

I am new to Coding, But using tutorials I have so far created a little story app data blinded using class. I want to implement a Sharing ContextMenu on the XAML below.

**Story.xaml**

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ListParagraph"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListParas}" 
         Loaded="ListParagraph_Loaded" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ts:ParagraphTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                    <ts:ParagraphTemplateSelector>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Margin="10,0"  >

                                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu"> 
                                       <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Share"
                                           Header="Share" Click="Share_Click"/>
                                     </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>


                                <TextBlock  x:Name="Detail" 
                                     Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"
                                      TextWrapping="Wrap">

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
               </ts:ParagraphTemplateSelector>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Here is the **Story.xaml.cs**

```
private void Share_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShareStatusTask shareStatusTask = new ShareStatusTask();
        shareStatusTask.Status = "";
        shareStatusTask.Show();
    }
```

I searched the internet two days for this **Share Status task/Share Linktask** . But all I cound find was sample smales like the above .cs file. What should I add to `shareStatusTask.Status = "";` to share the Data in the Above `XAML` file?

Comment: @dkozl Please take a look at this Question. No one is helping me out of this.

Comment: Please help me anyboady